# SQL - 2nd highest record in table

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT MAX(Score)
FROM Students
WHERE Score < (SELECT MAX(Score) FROM Students);
```

the above query works perfectly and fetches the record that has 2nd highest score, whereas the query mentioned below does not fetch anything

```
SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE Score < (SELECT MAX(Score) FROM Students);
```

here Students is the table from which I want to fetch all the details of that record which has 2nd highest score in the entire table.

I want that 2nd query should get executed, thanks in advance for helping me out.

- I have not used any database, I'm simply trying out these queries in w3schools.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your second query should work.

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a tie, two rows with the maximum score?

Comment: The best answer for MS-SQL-Server won't work in MySQL, for example.  Knowing the DBMS you're actually using is important.

Answer (score 1):

With standard SQL, this is typically solved using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select *
from (
  select *, dense_rank() over (order by score desc) as rnk
  from students
) t
where rnk = 2;
```

The above is ANSI standard SQL and works on all modern DBMS.

Comment: That's a low blow against people confined to using MySQL ;)

Comment: @MatBailie: even MySQL arrived in the 21st century: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Comment: That's ***still*** not a stable release yet, and even when it is many people will remain confined to MySQL 5.x *(which has releases in 2018)*.

Comment: @MatBailie: well, the question is tagged with `sql` which refers to standard SQL...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the query that you have suggested is not getting executed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what does "t" after closing bracket signify?

Comment: @ArchitaSundaray: it's an alias for the derived table. The same thing as e.g. `select * from students t`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok understood but the query is throwing error - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'dense_rank() over (order by rank desc)'.

Comment: @ArchitaSundaray: then the DBMS you are using doesn't support [modern SQL](https://modern-sql.com/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, I was initially trying out in w3schools n it didn't work out, so what do u suggest - where should I test it?

Answer (score 0):

How about ordering and getting the first record returned using `LIMIT`:

`SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE Score < (SELECT MAX(Score) FROM Students)
ORDER BY Score DESC
LIMIT 1;`

Comment: your suggested query is not getting executed

Comment: There was a semicolon in between. Try again.

Comment: I removed that from the 3rd line, still it was not working

Comment: I cannot help you any further without knowing the rdbms you are on.